# Can't get my custom godaddy domain to link with my heroku app:

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

My heroku app is not linking to my godaddy custom domain

I've tried changing the cname to host to "www" and the "points to" to the heroku dns target I was given. Still it has not worked. I've also tried putting the url of the heroku app:

https://agile-thicket-51202.herokuapp.com/

I've tried the forwarding settings in godaddy as well but was unsuccessful.

(My custom domain has already been verified on heroku)

```
 This is how it appears on my godaddy dns settings:

  CNAME www "herokudnstarget"
```

Could other dns settings be interfering with this?

Answer (score 0):

While working with cname GoDaddy only allows you to point www subdomain.For naked domain pointing use cloudflare or heroku add-on pointDNS.